# Xpath case insensitve query to parse hyperlinks

Tags: php, xpath, hyperlink

I have tried many different combinations in order to get this to function the results vary from "no results" to simply producing various errors.
What I am trying to do is search for all specified links on a web page containing part words or numbers... For example this works :

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@href, \'sweet\')]/@href');
```

And searches for all hrefs that contain "sweet" in any part of the href... problem it's case sensitive and almost all of the URL's contain PHP query strings with usernames that allow for mixed upper and lower case in the string, so this is one of my many failed attempts and making the query case insensitive :

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[contains(translate(\'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\',\'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\'),\'@href\', \'sweet\')]/@href');
```

I think I am on the right track but have the syntax wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[contains(translate(@href, 
                                               \'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\',
                                               \'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\'
                                              ), 
                                     \'sweet\'
                                    )
                           ]/@href');
```

instead.

Comment: That searches just fine but it is still case sensitive... It will match 'sweet' but not 'Sweet' ... thank you for helping by the way.

Comment: I am just thinking maybe I could parse the whole webpage to upper or lower case in an array and then perform the search? sounds overkill though maybe.

Comment: A typical href example that I am searching for would look like this http://example.com/livecam.php?username=SweetStella&c=1768 but the upper and lower case letters could be in any part of the string not just in the username=

Comment: This URL is not available.

Comment: I know that was just an example of what the urls on the pages look like, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have still not figured this one out it all looks like it should work but simply does not.

Comment: I think you should provide a simple input XML that does not work as part of your question. Otherwise nobody will be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fn:contains` with `fn:translate` is the wrong approach, which is evidenced through how complicated it is for you to achieve this simple task.

If you have XPath 2.0, you could instead use `fn:matches`, for example:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//a[matches(@href, 'sweet', 'i')]/@href");
```

Note that the 3rd argument to fn:matches is some flags to control the evaluation of the expression, in this case we have specified `i` which means the comparison is case-insensitive. Arguably your query could also be simplified to:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//a/@href[matches(., 'sweet', 'i')]");
```

If you are stuck on XPath 1.0, then you could simply use an `or` expression with two `fn:contains` expressions, for example:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//a/@href[contains(., 'sweet') or contains(., 'SWEET')]");
```

Also in XQuery you can use either single or double quotes, so to make your code more readable I have used the single quotes, so that you do not need to escape the double quotes in the XQuery from your PHP code.

Comment: Hi, your version just throws up errors, I have tried many versions of using the 'i' switch and was lead to believe that it will not work in an xpath query that is when I found the 'abcd....' etc way and started to play with that... thank you for taking a look

Comment: Ah okay it sounds like you are stuck on XPath 1.0. That is too bad, as it really is poor compare to XPath 2.0 or 3.0. My example was in XQuery 2.0. I have added an updated XQuery 1.0 version as well...

Comment: Righto the XQuery 1.0 Ver works without errors thank you for showing me that, however it really does need to be case insensitive since there could be any mixed combination in the URL including numbers or 'L33T' speak, would be easier to show you the source for one of the live pages but since its all adult content I can't do that here lol